Saving a GIF from a byte array will have a seemingly random time in the gallery app
I am trying to make an app where users are able to share images and GIFs with each other. Saving images seems to be going fine there are not many issues on that part, however for saving GIFs a little while after saving them they jump to another time in the gallery app (this can be a couple of minutes, a couple of days or for one image even a year). The GIFs are displayed correctly after saving, but I would like them to be in the correct order. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this or maybe even how to fix it?
I tried the following solution(firebase included in case that matters):
storage.reference.child(claimPath).getBytes(1_000_000_000).addOnSuccessListener { bytes ->
            val path =
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    .toString()
            val file = File(path + File.separator + claimPath.replace("claim_images/", ""))
            file.writeBytes(bytes)
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
                this, arrayOf(file.absolutePath),
                null
            ) { path, uri ->
                Toast.makeText(this@SingleClaimScreen, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

